# Index on Composite attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, composite-index

When we create an index on an attribute a tree is created for this attribute.
But what happens when we create an index with composite attributes? Two trees are created? Both are part of the same tree? What?

Comment: I remember having read something about having 1 index with concatenated values from composite columns. That's why you can't revert columns orders when wanting to seek through a composite index.

Comment: You mean concating actual values?

Comment: yes, I think. The b-tree works like this I think

Comment: oh, but then I don't know if the values are concatenated or if some kind of hash is applied before.

Comment: see this description of a b-tree in Oracle faq: http://www.orafaq.com/node/1403 It might help you correlate to mysql

Answer (score 1):

It concats the attributes in the same order as you have mentioned. It for the same reason, if you have an composite index on columns a,b,c in the same order, the index will be useful only if the left columns are searched

```
WHERE a=4 ## uses index
WHERE a=4 and b=10 ## uses index
WHERE b=10 ## doesnot use index
```