# Indexing on composite key

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, indexing

If I have a table and I create a  index on Emp.Id, Emp.Name and Emp.Surname .(3 fields out of 10).
Now if I query table with just Emp.Id will it fetch query based upon indexing (fast) or normal?

Comment: Got solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349110/index-on-composite-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Think of a telephone book.

It's indexed on `last_name` first, then `first_name`.

Does this help you look up a person by their last name only? Yes.

Does it help you look up a person by their first name only? No.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is the first column in the index, then it can be used for a query filtering on the `id`.

This is a common practice when creating indexes, putting commonly used columns first, but then including others.